# Error in read.table - number of elements in a specific line

Tags: r

I am trying to read.table  data in clipboard to get around DRM-ed file. But I could not understand why it does not work as below. I added " comment.char="" " and it didn't help.

> t1 = read.table( "clipboard", header=T, sep="\t"  )

Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
line 23938 did not have 23 elements

> t1_0 = readLines( "clipboard" )
>
> t2 = sapply( t1_0, function(x) strsplit(x, "\t") )
>
> table( sapply(t2, length ) )

23

406799

Comment: This question isn't possible to answer without knowing the contents of "clipboard" (particularly line 23938). Is it possible there are extra tab characters within fields?

Comment: Rather than using `readLines` and `strplit`, the `count.fields()` function will tell you how many fields `read.table()` will see. Try `table(count.fields("clipboard", sep="\t"))`

Comment: If there are extra tabs within fields, I guess my strsplit run should spit out different number, isn't it?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks!  count.fields shows that different field counts. Still no idea why this happens. I got around this problem by manually strsplit and rbind them.

Comment: Unless you can extract those lines or otherwise create a reproducible example, it's unlikely we will be able to help you any further.

Comment: In some field can be a quote and this could cause a problem. Try to call `read.table` with the `quote=""` argument.

Comment: Use of quote as advised and comment.char args together helped me out. Thanks! @nicola, DavidRobinson and MrFlick